# JavaScript and ASP.. How do I create an if statement that looks at the value of an asp drop down control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following javascript works with a simple test site i made, but does not work when i put it into my production site.
in..:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    strLen = function(input){
var errorLabel = document.getElementById("errorLabel");
var drpDown = document.getElementById("Select1");
if (drpDown.value == "USA")
if (errorLabel)
    errorLabel.style.display = input.value.length > 2 ? "block" : "none" ;
if (drpDown.value != "USA")
    errorLabel.style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<asp:textbox id="txtShipState" CssClass="style5" TabIndex="2" runat="server"
    Width="40px" MaxLength="10" onkeyup="strLen(this)"></asp:textbox>&nbsp;

<asp:dropdownlist id="drpShipCountry" runat="server" style="display:none"
    AutoPostBack="true" TabIndex="2"></asp:dropdownlist>

<select name="drpShipCountry"onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'drpShipCountry\',\'\')', 0)" id="Select1" tabindex="2">
<option selected="selected" value="USA">United States</option>
<option value="ALB">Albania</option>
<option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
<option value="ATA">Antarctica</option>
<option value="ATG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
</select>
```

i dont know where or how its being added.. i shortened the list because its very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=DropDown1.UniqueID%>"); 
if (ddl){
    if (ddl.Value == "United States"){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After looking at your revised question, please try the following instead:

```
var ddlList = document.getElementsByName("drpShipCountry");
if (ddlList.length > 0){
    var ddl = ddlList[0];
    if(ddl){
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the js code but theres fine tuning now, and you may be able to help.. somewhere in the server the following is added: <select name="drpShipCountry" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'drpShipCountry\',\'\')', 0)" id="Select1" tabindex="2"> ...setting my dropdown id - to select1, so just to see change I hard coded it to read select1 .. it works on my test site, but not on my full running site, the difference is that the test site has the select in my html and the other site has the selected somewhere else i do not know where

Comment: I don't know why that code would be added in the code behind, but if you can take it out you probably should. Now if I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like your problem might have to do with the way ASP.NET assigns IDs to controls.

Comment: yes, that is where i am getting hung up, and I do not know where I'd take that code out, and how much it would affect the control, because there are multiple sites that use this page, and each one has different selections in the drop down

Comment: If the control is renamed to Select1, you could try getElementById("<%=Select1.UniqueID%>"), or try setting ClientIDMode to static in the web.config.

Comment: i have tried getElementById("<%=Select1.UniqueID%>") and any time i use it i get a compilation error, I will try looking into the web.config now..there is no ClientIDMode set in the web.config file, where would I add it

Comment: If you set ClientIDMode to static, you should be able to reference the dropdown as "Select1"

Comment: I am trying to find where I am supposed to set ClientIDMode = Static, it is listed nowhere in my web.config file, like is it supposed to be in the configurations tags or appsettings.. thats what I'm looking for

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework 4.0? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I do believe we are using 4.0 not 100% .. but we are currently using VS 2005, in the process of making the change to 2010

Comment: Try typing ClientIDMode into the page directive, or directly into the control. Does intellisense pick it up?

Comment: Can you revise your question and post some code showing how that Select1 dropdown is being generated?

Comment: I have added the reqeusted lines to it, but I do not know where that code is being generated.

Comment: that last edit came up with the alert box! we are getting somewhere haha, sorry for late response i was on lunch

Comment: Thank you again! I was able to get it to work from there, many thanks to you